# System.Data.sqlClient.sqlError: cannt open backup device ....operating system error2( error not found )

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

I am working with SQl server 2005 and I am trying to back up the database using SQL server management studio Express  but I encountered this error

**System.Data.sqlClient.sqlError: cannt open backup device 'E:........' operating system error2( error not found ).**

Even if i try to back up the device on another directory like c fore example I still having the same      error .

Please how can I solve this Error ?

Please Help me Since I am new to Sql server ......

Comment: It's probably a windows permission issue for the user that SQL Server is set to run under (see configuration manager to find out which account that is).

Comment: @Bridge how can I see the configuration  manager ? can you help me more Please ??

Comment: @Bridge Can you help me more Please ??

Comment: You would have installed it alongside the SQL Server instance I expect - look in program files in the "Configuration tools" folder. Once you've got it open, go to services on the left, find the SQL Server instance on the right and look at the "Log On As" column to find the user that the instance is running under. After that, you need to configure the windows permissions for that account - good luck!

Comment: @Bridge Thanks for helping me ... I found it and the  "Log On As" column is Local System . How can I configure the permissions ?? please I am  new in this domain

Comment: Odd - Local system should have access to pretty much everything by default. It's not my area of expertise I'm afraid - ask whoever runs your network? You should create a windows account with appropriate permissions and run the SQL Server service under that account instead.